# Eclipse with Tomcat 8 and maven crash only after 1 minute

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I can compile and run my project on Tomcat 8 using Eclipse neon.
The project is built with maven and Spring MVC. But only after or less than one minute I have to compile and run the project again. I get the error below:

```
 Dec 30, 2015 9:38:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
 INFO: Reloading Context with name [/test] has started
 Dec 30, 2015 9:38:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
 Dec 30, 2015 9:38:10 PM  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
 INFO: Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 30 21:37:27 CET 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
 Dec 30, 2015 9:38:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
 Dec 30, 2015 9:38:10 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Dec 30 21:37:23     CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
 Dec 30, 2015 9:38:10 PM   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean destroy
 INFO: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'guarding'
Dec 30, 2015 9:38:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 Dec 30, 2015 9:38:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
 INFO: Reloading Context with name [/test] is completed
```

Can anybody understand why and what is depends on ?
Happy new year to every one!

Comment: This is not an error. It's just messages from Tomcat informing you that it's reloading a context (and thus shutting down the app)

Comment: But I have to compile and reload the project, for example if I'm updating some user it crash and same compiling/reloading procedure. Is there some way I can continue to work? and work around the compile and reloading?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm updating some user"? And by "it crash"? What are you doing, and what happens, precisely? If there is an error, what is it? What does 'compile and reloading" means? Tomcat doesn't compile anything.

Comment: When compiling and running the project at localhost with firefox I get a 404 page after the app  shutting down

Comment: That's quite expected. If the app has shut down, you can't acess any of its resources. You're not answering any of my questions.

Comment: I did not get any answer neither. My question was and still is :Why the app is shut down?

Comment: We can't know, because you refuse to tell us what you're doing when it shuts down, if an exception happens before it shuts down, etc. All we vaguely know is that you "update a user". But what is a user? We don't know. Do you update a user of your OS? Do you edit a User class? Do you modify the users in the tomcat user file? You could tell us, but you refuse doing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99354/discussion-between-user1067665-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Thanks to JB Nizet.

1) Double clicking server in Eclipse
2) On publishing chose the first alternative (Never public automatically)
3) Save the change.

Thanks all!